# Как импортировать сгенерированный PrismaClient из папки node_modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, prisma

Дано.

В бэкенд-приложении есть два микросервиса `trainings`(тренировки) и `gyms`(спортивные залы).
Каждый микросервис использует свою БД(PostgreSQL).
Взаимодействие с БД осуществляется с помощью PrismaORM.
Приложение строится с использованием монорепозитория, для всех микросервисов используется единая папка `node_modules/`
Мне нужно сгенерировать 2 PrismaClient-а (от микросервисов `trainings` и `gyms`) в эту папку `node_modules`.

Для этого я сделал следующее:

- в микросервисе `trainings`, в файле schema.prisma я указал путь куда будет генерироваться клиент

```
    generator client {
      provider = "prisma-client-js"
      output = "../../../node_modules/.prisma/client-trainings"
    }
```

- тоже самое я сделал для микросервиса `gyms` (в поле output путь до папки куда генерируется клиент)

```
    generator client {
      provider = "prisma-client-js"
      output = "../../../node_modules/.prisma/client-gyms"
    }
```

Оба клиента были успешно сгенерированы после того как я вызвал команды:

- `nx run trainings:db-generate`;
- `nx run gyms:db-generate`;

На всякий случай укажу какие действия вызывают эти команды.
Данные команды у меня описаны в файле **project.json**:

```
"db-generate": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "command": "npx prisma generate --schema ./prisma/schema.prisma",
        "cwd": "apps/gyms"
      }
 },
```

---

А вот теперь собственно сам вопрос.
Когда у меня был 1 микросервис `trainings` я в файлы, где описывал логику приложения, импортировал PrismaClient следующим образом:

`import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';`

Но после того как я добавил второй клиент от микросервиса `gyms` сокращённая запись не работает, например:

- `import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client-gyms';` или
- `import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client-trainings';`

Появляется ошибка - *Cannot find module '@prisma/client-gyms' or its corresponding type declarations.*

Поэтому я вынужден импортировать PrismaClient полностью прописывая путь до него, например вот так:

- `import { PrismaClient } from '../../../../../node_modules/.prisma/client-gyms';` или
- `import { PrismaClient } from '../../../../../node_modules/.prisma/client-trainins';`

Как можно избавиться от такой длинной записи???

---

И второй вопрос, он даже более важный чем предыдущий.
Оба микросервиса (`trainings` и `gyms`) перестали запускаться, когда я вызываю следующие команды:

- `nx run trainins:serve`,
- `nx run gyms:serve`

Данные команды у меня описаны в файле **project.json**:

```
"serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/js:node",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "gyms:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "gyms:build:production"
        }
      }
},
```

Каждый раз когда я вызываю эту команду у меня выскакивает следующая ошибка:
`[Nest] 1556  - 17.04.2023, 19:17:15   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\simae\Desktop\FitFriends\fit-friends\dist\apps\gyms\schema.prisma'`

У меня есть подозрение, что данная проблема связана с тем что у меня теперь *два* PrismaClient-a.
Во всяком случае до того когда у меня был *один* микросервис и *один* PrismaClient таких проблем не было.

Не уверен что мне тут смогут помочь, но на всякий случай опубликую вопрос, попытка не пытка :)
Сам я уже с этим вопросом вожусь больше суток, перерыл всю доку по призме, но так и не смог разобраться. К сожалению опыта и знаний пока не достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Опытные товарищи подсказали мне в чём проблема.
На всякий случай опубликую здесь ответ. Проблема специфичная, но тем не менее может возникнуть у тех, кто будет работать с микросервисами.

В файле schema.prisma в поле output нужно было использовать **@** вместо точки,
таким образом:

`output = "../../../node_modules/@prisma/client-trainings"`

После этого уже можно обращаться к клиенту так:

`import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client-trainings';`

Ну и проблема с запуском микросервисов после внесённых изменений решилась.